# Prestiti dallo spagnolo al plurale

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, plural

Solitamente i prestiti dalle lingue straniere si prendono al singolare. Così abbiamo lo stage, il blitz, il residence. Però con lo spagnolo ci sono curiose eccezioni: si dice "il murales, il peones" e non "il mural, il peon". Qualcuno ha idea del motivo di questa curiosità?

Comment: Ignoranza o stupidità valgono?

Comment: sì, ma dovrebbero valere anche per prrstiti da altre lingue, no?

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis: decisamente non un problema strettamente italiano... inglesi e francesi fanno lo stesso con i prestiti dall'italiano ad esempio.

Comment: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/murales-singolare-plurale

Comment: *Il peones*? **Mai** sentito. Una parola che invece sento molto frequentemente è *silos*.

Comment: @Bakuriu *silo* viene dal greco, non dallo spagnolo!

Comment: @Agos E allora? È sempre un plurale usato come singolare. (Questo tra l'altro risponde a metà domanda: lo spagnolo *non* è l'unica lingua da cui ciò è avvenuto).

Comment: a dire il vero il De Mauro dice che *silo* (che è anche una parola italiana...) arriva dallo spagnolo via il francese. Per "un peones", una ricerca su Google dà un 18000 risultati, che non sono molti ma neppure pochissimi.

Comment: sentiamo anche: la paella, la siesta, i marines, i blue jeans...

Comment: @Sklivvz: Perché citi la paella e la siesta? Nessuno ha detto che *tutti* i prestiti dallo spagnolo siano al plurale.

Comment: A proposito di “silo(s)”, l'etimo dato dal Treccani è “dallo spagn. *silo*, che, come il provenz. ant. *sil*, è dal lat. *sirus*, gr. σιρός o σειρός «granaio»”. Quindi il greco c'entra, ma molto alla lontana.

Comment: Questo non è specifico al Italiano. Almeno in Inglese e in Francese, e probabilmente in molti altri lingue, "il spaghetto" se dice "the/le spaghetti" e "il tifoso" spesso "the/le tifosi".

Comment: @jlliagre “The spaghetti“ in inglese è, in generale, sbagliato, perché “spaghetti” è “uncountable”, come “milk”. Mi sorprendono molto di più *eating a panini* o *eating lasagna*, per non parlare di *linguini* (che è privo di senso).

Comment: @egreg En francese anche diciamo "un panini", mai "un panino".

Comment: @jlliagre: ma in francese (e in inglese) *panini* ha un significato leggermente diverso da *panino* in italiano, indicando solamente un sandwich grigliato (che non è il caso in italiano).

Comment: @egreg concesso, pero anche stanno al singolare in francese queste parole: "ravioli", "brocoli", "gnocchi", "graffiti", "salami", "paparazzi"

Comment: Io ho letto, su un libro che non trovo più, ma forse era "Il salva-italiano", che le parole straniere si usano sempre invariate, *tranne* che quelle spagnole. Lo ricordo bene perché la cosa mi è parsa strana ma nemmeno troppo.

Answer (score 4):

È semplicemente il modo in cui sono arrivate a noi. Ci sono certe parole che sono associate ad un contesto, e venendo usate sempre in quel contesto perdono la loro accezione di origine e vengono usate solo al plurale. Se la parola in questione è di origine straniera,  il discorso è uguale,  e non vale solo per lo spagnolo: pensa per esempio alla parola "media" (da mass media). Ha la terminazione del plurale (dal latino), e solo così viene usata.

Comment: +1 E non è specifico al Italiano, stanno al singolare in Francese queste parole: "ravioli", "brocoli", "gnocchi", "graffiti", "salami", "paparazzi" ...

Comment: "paparazzi" **started** as a name in -i, and then was retrofitted for Italian :-)

Comment: @mau The word "Paparazzo" was born in 1960 to name a photographer in Fellini's "La dolce vita". "Paparazzi" definitely came later.

Comment: I stand corrected. I knew about the origin, but I always thought the surname was ending in -i.

Comment: tristemente vero. Aggiungo che spesso sento i miei colleghi informatici usare termini tecnici inglesi al plurale come se fossero al singolare, e, se glielo faccio notare, mi dicono che non percepiscono il plurale nella parola (il che la dice lunga sull'insegnamento dell'inglese nella scuola italiana)

Comment: Hai qualche fonte?

Comment: @linuxfan: C'è una fonte nel commento di giordano, ma hai ragione: sarebbe stato meglio includerla nella risposta. Se vuoi, puoi scrivere una risposta basandoti nel contenuto di questa fonte.

Answer (score -2):

Nell'immaginario italiano, per parlare in spagnolo è sufficente mettere una "S" alla fine di tutte le parole.

Non mi sorprenderebbe che questa fosse la ragione per cui le parole spagnole vengono prese in prestito al plurale.